# Background Fetch runs once on Xamarin.ios for iOS 9 +

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, xamarin.ios, background-fetch

I'd like to have a background fetch in Xamarin.ios.

As I've followed this tutorial : https://github.com/Redth/iOS.BackgroundFetch.Sample, when I run application ,on a simulator, in background fetch mode, application calls only one time PerformFetch method and not more !! (I've waited 1 hour and nothing happened)

In info.plist, I've turned on Background mode and Background fetch and in xml file, I have :

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
    </array>
```

In FinishedLaunching I have  :

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.BackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum);
```

and here is my PerformFetch function :

```
public override void PerformFetch(UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
}
```

Do I have to do another thing for have a repetition call on PerformFetch function? I've added Push Notifications on application certificate but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Background fetch can take a lot more time than just 1 hour. You can set the minimum time that is required to get a fetch but you can not set the maximum value.

The system itself will determine if there is a good situation to fetch.

More info at the Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically section:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: For different value in UIApplication.BackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum, I have no repetition ! But I let it turn all the night and tomorrow morning I'll accept your response if it gets the fetch :)

Comment: It doesn't work ! Is there any other configuration for having Fetch in background?

Comment: Check if the Backgrounf App Refresh is enabled.
You can adjust your apps' background activity in Settings > General > Background App Refresh.

Comment: In Xamarin, I've already activated Background Mode and then Background Fetch !